# My spectron app.client doesn't contains all the methods

Tags: electron, spectron

I'm trying to test my electron app using spectron and mocha, here is my file 'first.js' containing my tests:

```html
const assert = require('assert');
const path = require('path');
const {Application} = require('spectron');
const electronPath = require('electron');


describe('GULP Tests', function () {
    this.timeout(30000)

    const app = new Application({
        path: electronPath,
        args: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'main.js')]
    });


    //Start the electron app before each test
    before(() => {

        return app.start();
    });

    //Stop the electron app after completion of each test
    after(() => {
        if (app && app.isRunning()) {
            return app.stop();
        }
    });

    it('Is window opened', async () => {
        const count = await app.client.getWindowCount();
        return assert.equal(count, 1);
    });

    it('Clicks on the project creation button', async () => {
       await app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded();
       const title = await app.client.
       console.log(title);
       return assert.equal(title, 'Welcome to GULP, !');
    });

});
```

My first test is passing, but for the second one i'd like to do a click on an element, but my app.client does not contain a .click methods, and also no getText or getHTML. I've tried to import browser from webdriverio but it was the same problem, I get an error when testing saying me that those methods doesn't exists. I've red the spectron documentation and they're using .click and .getText methods regularly, why I don't get them ? I've imported spectron as it's said in the documentation to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with the same issue for a while. After much trial and error i changed my async methods to normal functions.

```
it('Clicks on the project creation button', function() {
   app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded();
   const title = await app.client.
   console.log(title);
   return assert.equal(title, 'Welcome to GULP, !');
});
```

Strange but it worked for me. hopefully it helps.